# XBox 360 - NBA 2K13 MyCareer: Which achievements still work?

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, nba2k13

Yesterday I figured I would go back and work through some of the achievements I missed in MyCareer. With the NBA2K13 servers gone now, I figured this may be problematic. It appears some of them work with the online only VC (Virtual Currency) and some work with either VC or the offline SP (Skill Points).  I was able to make the 'Now Playing' achievement pop by purchasing a pre-game ritual using SPs but not the 'NBA Cares' when I purchased the fans booster.  Is there a list somewhere that mentions this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use TrueAchievements for stats on achievements like this.  The general community on TA is very active on flagging categories for achievements including when an achievement becomes unobtainable.  I have not personally played this game, nor can I verify which achievements are unobtainable.  However, the TA community keeps all of this information up to date on all Xbox games.

http://www.trueachievements.com/NBA-2K13/achievements.htm

According to TrueAchievements there are currently, as of today 2015-08-05, 15 discontinued achievements in this game.  They are listed as follows:

- Another Day, Another Win
- Back to Back to Back
- Don't Hate the Player
- From the Ground Up
- Hamilton
- Lincoln
- On the Road Again
- Not Your Father's Association
- Remaking History
- Runneth Over
- The Here and Now
- The Sum of Its Parts
- This One Counts
- To Good Use
- You're Officially Hot

However, I would recommend looking at the link because it will be an up to date list at any time.  This is a static list that I am taking from their information, so it won't change.  Plus I can not check to see if this list is correct or not.